# how can Extract information from the site with javascript with json?

Tags: javascript, html

Your code is executed as native in the browser, so you can't use any packages or
You don't have an external framework like jQuery. Also permitted to use items specified in 6ES
JavaScript languages ​​have been added, like you don't have let and const.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please see this article first https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also add your current attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could your provide an example of the data you are trying to extract? There is an built-in Method in ES5 to work with json.

```
JSON.stringify(value)
```